# javac not showing up in .bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I was writing a .bat file to automatically compile and run programs based on file extension when I encountered a strange problem with `javac`.  Here's a snippet of my .bat file:

```
...
echo javac %1
javac %1
...
```

The program gives the  error

```
javac "C:\MY\FILE.java"
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

, which I know usually means that my path isn't configured properly.  This can't be the case here because typing `javac C:\MY\FILE.java` works without a hitch.  My path starts with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` and  `java -version` is 1.7.0 to match.  Is there any reason that I'm getting different results with a .bat file than I am for typing directly to the console?

Comment: When you use echo , it has nothing to do with Javac... it seems your path is not configured.. can u check again

Comment: Have you reset the PATH variable elsewhere in the batch file.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your problem, but having spaces in your path for things like this tends to break scripts. You might want to move your jdk to something like c:\jdk1.7.0. This would require uninstall/reinstall, then update your path.

Comment: @aquaraga No, I do not set my path elsewhere in the batch file.

Comment: @Vineet My path must be configured correctly, since running the same command directly from the command line works just fine.

Comment: @Bill Spaces in the directory name isn't the problem either.  I used mklink and changed my path variable to C:\JDK\bin\ to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0"

echo %JAVA_HOME\bin\javac %1
%JAVA_HOME\bin\javac %1
```

Comment: ~1 and ~2 is used for short path in MS-DOS